# Can I create a watch extension with only an iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-watch

What I am trying to do is to create an iPad only app and create a watch extension to it.
We want 0 dependency on an iPhone app.
Is it possible?

Comment: I think they mentioned in WWDC19 that you can now create standalone watch apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no :(
https://www.lifewire.com/can-you-use-apple-watch-with-ipad-1994095

Answer (score 1):

Apple Watch can’t be paired to an iPad, so developers can’t transfer data between the two devices through the WatchConnectivity framework. What you can do is create a standalone watchOS 6 app that syncs data with iPadOS through WiFi and cellular (Apple Watch models that support cellular starting with Series 3).